# WebdDriverManager throwing NoSuchFileException for AWS EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, webdrivermanager-java

I am executing my Selenium tests on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance from Windows OS using RemoteWebDriver.

**Below is the Selenium code:**

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://18.118.213.92:4444/wd/hub"), co);
```

**But it is throwing the below error:**

```
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/15425606072528251971
    at testing.RediffLoginTest.bmeth(RediffLoginTest.java:55)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/15425606072528251971
    at testing.RediffLoginTest.bmeth(RediffLoginTest.java:55)
```

Normally, when we execute tests on Windows OS, then the above code downloads the browser drivers automatically to the cache folder in user directory.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you display your `http://<public ip address of AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance>` please?

Comment: Have added the public ip address.

Comment: this public ip is a secret?

Comment: Actually, I dont know much about AWS EC2, I am just using for Selenium testing purposes based on the online tutorials.

Comment: @Boni García: Can you please help on this issues ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using remote browsers, so you don't need WebDriverManager (i.e., remove line `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();`).

Comment: Can you please explain in detail as to why should I remove this line for remote browsers and how to make use of WebDriverManager in such a case ?

Comment: WebDriverManager is typically used to resolver driver for local browsers. If you are consuming remote browser (e.g., with Selenium Grid), the drivers should be resolved in the Selenium Server side.

Comment: So, in case of Selenium Grid, there is no way to manage browser binaries using WebDriverManager. That means I have to manually download the drivers on the node machines and give the driver path while registering the nodes ?

Comment: https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#selenium-grid